# How do I include a library / API into my Behat project that was added by Composer?

Tags: php, composer-php, behat

Apparently [version 4 of PHPUnit now uses Composer](https://github.com/Behat/CommonContexts/issues/51) to autoload, which means that the usual means of including PHPUnit in Behat version 2:

```
require_once 'PHPUnit/Autoload.php';
require_once 'PHPUnit/Framework/Assert/Functions.php';
```

Doesn't work. I was hoping that `/vendor/autoload.php` in my Behat folder would include it but it seems like it's not the case.

I guess what I'm asking is what is the general way in which I can include into my code a library that was added by Composer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can successfully use default `/vendor/autoload.php` to both load your libraries and your code. It's hard to say exactly what might be wrong without further details, but make sure your composer dependencies are updated and then simply require the composer's `authoload.php`. The composer.json should look similar to:

```
{
    "require": {
        "behat/behat": "dev-master",
        "behat/mink": "dev-master",
        "behat/mink-extension": "dev-master",
        "behat/mink-browserkit-driver": "dev-master",
        "behat/mink-goutte-driver": "dev-master",
        "behat/mink-selenium2-driver": "dev-master",
        "phpunit/dbunit": "*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "*",
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {
            "": "./src/"
        }
    }
}
```

You can include it in your context hook (this is Behat 3 example though):

```
/**
 * @beforeSuite
 */
public static function setUpSuite()
{
    require_once './vendor/autoload.php';
}
```